SFMC Mobile Push Demographics - querying LastAppOpen, LastMessageOpen, LastSend, MessageOpenCount
I am working with a client that is looking to query MobilePush Demographics data such as LastAppOpen, LastMessageOpen, LastSend, MessageOpenCount. However, it seems these fields are not found in the _PushAddress data view. Has anyone had any luck querying for these data points?
